# Calorimetry- Calculating change in temperature help

Tags: calorimetry

The reaction: Zn(s) + 2 AgNO3 (aq) → 2 Ag(s) + Zn(NO3)2 (aq)
takes place in a calorimeter.
30 cm3 of a 1.20 mol dm−3 solution of silver nitrate with an excess of zinc is used. If the value of ∆rH is −365.1 kJ mol−1 and all solutions are assumed to have a density of 1.00 g cm−3 and a specific heat capacity of 4.18 J K−1 g−1, what temperature change is produced?

I attempted to calculate the value of Q and got 13,143.6 J. Then substituted this into
Q = M x C x deltaT, to rearrange the equation giving delta T.

The answer I got is 105 but this is incorrect.

Comment: If you want to know where you made the error,  provide your detailed calculation procedure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The $\pu{Delta H}$ value is $\pu{-365 kJ/mol}$. This is supposed to be "per mole of what happens in the equation with a coefficient $1$". So it is per mole of Zinc. It can also be rewritten so : $\ce{\Delta H = -365 kJ (mol Zn)^{-1} = -365 kJ (2 mol AgNO3)^{-1} = - 182.5 kJ (mol AgNO3)^{-1}}$ And here, you are using $\ce{0.036 mol AgNO3}$. So the heat effect is twice smaller. : $\pu{\Delta T = 52.3 K}$